# How do I declare an array that can be used multiple times?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm *sort of* new to PHP / Wordpress and am struggling trying to get something to work.

Basically, I'm trying to make a section in the theme customizer that lets me select from an array of Google Fonts.

I have my array like so:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
'site_title',
array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'label' => 'Site Title:',
    'section' => 'typography_section_one',
    'choices' => array("ABeeZee" => "ABeeZee",
          "Abel" => "Abel",
          "Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
          "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
          "Acme" => "Acme",
          "Actor" => "Actor",
          "Adamina" => "Adamina",
          etc...
    )
   )
);
}

add_action( 'customize_register', 'type_customizer' );
```

So, this all works fine. No problems at all. I can see my section, I can change my fonts, it's all great.

However I want a few instances of this, so users can change the fonts of multiple sections of their site. Thing is, I don't want to have to keep copy and pasting this huge array of font names every single time I create a new control.

So, here's my question. Is there anyway I can "globalise" this array so it can be used multiple times?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to put the array in it's own file.

**my_fonts.php**

```
<?php

$fonts = array(
    "Abel" => "Abel",
    "Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
    "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
    "Acme" => "Acme",
    "Actor" => "Actor",
    "Adamina" => "Adamina",
);

return $fonts;
```

Then use it as follows:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'site_title',
    array(
        'type' => 'select',
        'label' => 'Site Title:',
        'section' => 'typography_section_one',
        'choices' => include('my_fonts.php'),
    )
);
```

If you are using php 7 you could also define the array as a constant as follows:

```
define('MY_FONTS', array(
    "Abel" => "Abel",
    "Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
    "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
    "Acme" => "Acme",
    "Actor" => "Actor",
    "Adamina" => "Adamina",
));
```

Comment: A-hah! Worked perfectly! Thanks so much Tom! :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

using the global keyword:

```
$fonts =  array("ABeeZee" => "ABeeZee",
      "Abel" => "Abel",
      "Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
      "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
      "Acme" => "Acme",
      "Actor" => "Actor",
      "Adamina" => "Adamina",
      etc...
);

function customize_register() {
    global $fonts;

    $wp_customize->add_control(
        'site_title',
        array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Site Title:',
            'section' => 'typography_section_one',
            'choices' => $fonts
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'type_customizer' );
```

Thw global keyword will pull the variable `$array` into the scope of the function, making it available there. This is the easiest and least advisable possibility.

The best way would be to wrap all your code into a class:

```
class foobar {

    var $fonts = array(
        "ABeeZee" => "ABeeZee",
        "Abel" => "Abel",
        "Abril Fatface" => "Abril+Fatface",
        "Aclonica" => "Aclonica",
        "Acme" => "Acme",
        "Actor" => "Actor",
        "Adamina" => "Adamina",
        etc...
    );

    function customize_register() {
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            'site_title',
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => 'Site Title:',
                'section' => 'typography_section_one',
                'choices' => $this->fonts
            )
        );
    }

    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'type_customizer' ) );
    }

}

$foo = new foobar();
```

This way you don't have to worry about collisions with other plugins/themes due to identical variable names, everything is cleanly wrapped inside a single class.